# Bulk Copy Using Wildcard in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Please be informed that, im trying to copy a bulk files from my source server to the destination server using ansible. While trying an error. Please help me.

```
---
- name: Going to copy bulk files
hosts: test
vars_prompt:
- name: copy
prompt: Enter the Bulk File to Copy
private: no
tasks:
- name: Copy bulk files
shell: cp /tmp/guru/{{ copy }}* /ansible/sri
```

Comment: Which error is thrown?

Comment: One thing for sure: you cannot "*copy a bulk files from my source server to the destination server*" by executing `cp` command.

Comment: "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2017-12-17 16:12:08.309199",
    "stderr": "cp: cannot stat ‘/tmp/guru/a*’: No such file or directory",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "cp: cannot stat ‘/tmp/guru/a*’: No such file or directory"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`shell` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/shell_module.html) executes a shell command **on the destination server**, which explains the error message `cp: cannot stat ‘/tmp/guru/a*’: No such file or directory`: the source files of the `cp` does not exists on the destination server.

Ansible provide a [lot of modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_all_modules.html) which are more appropriate to use than executing shell commands.

In your case, the [`copy` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html) is the one you need: it copies files from source server to destination server. You can combine it with a [`with_fileglob` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#id4):

```
tasks:
  - name: Copy bulk files
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /ansible/sri
    with_fileglob: "/tmp/guru/{{ copy }}*"
```

Comment: I get {"msg": "'copy' is undefined"}

Comment: In the original question, `copy` variable is in the `vars_prompt` section. You need to adapt to your use case by using or not a variable and defining it the way that suit your need (`group_var`, `vars_prompt`, extra var, ...)